# What is this icon design with unfinished border line called?

Tags: icon

I would like to know what is this type of design is called. It's used throughout Discord UI and is becoming an icon trend on Flaticon.

[image: Description]

Answer (score 1):

A notch?

In the case of the discord logo:

You can see it on some cardboard boxes, try any toothpaste box. It is there so when you fold the cardboard it does fold in the exact place, and do not push the other wall.

I can not show you any document, but "back in the years" when typography was made of metal (either mobil types or lines of text) when you had the joinings in small versions of the font, you made this notches, so the adjacent metal did not produced a rounded joint.

I faked an example:

[image]

A similar thing happened before, in roman letters, because when carving a letter on marble it was easier to have a serif that was progresively less deep than a sharp angle inside the marble.

[image]

So it was essentially a tool mark.

In the case of the icons, simmilar, they want to have an "engraving" look; another tool mark.

[image]

It also resamples me an ink drawing by hand. Sometimes the ink stopped flowing. It gives them a little less electronic look, and a bit more humanist look, vintage look.

Look at some pen drawings from Snoopy, Mafalda or any comic book.